# Derived to base conversion for template argument

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

```
struct CL1{};
struct CL2:CL1{};

template<CL1*>
struct TMPL{};

CL2 cl2;

int main()
{
    TMPL<&cl2> tmpl; //error: could not convert template argument ‘& cl2’ to ‘CL1*’
    return 0;
}
```

The Standard 2003 14.3.2/5 says:

> for a non-type template-parameter of type pointer to object,
>   qualification conversions (4.4) and the array-to-pointer conversion
>   (4.2) are applied. [Note: In particular, neither the null pointer
>   conversion (4.10) **nor the derived-to-base conversion (4.10) are
>   applied**. Although 0 is a valid template-argument for a non-type
>   template-parameter of integral type, it is not a valid
>   template-argument for a non-type template-parameter of pointer type. ]

Why such restrictions applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 reasons IMHO:

1. Addresses are not known until link time. That's well after any template expansion decisions have been made. Indeed in position independent code, addresses are not known until run time.
2. There is a longstanding ambiguity between (type *)0 and int(0). c++11 cures this with the nullptr value of nullptr_t class.